# Running a pod as a service account to connect to a database with Integrated Security

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks

I have a `.NET Core` service running on `Azure Kubernetes Service` and a Linux Docker image. It needs to connect to an on-premise database with Integrated Security. One of the service accounts in my on-premise AD has access to this database.

My question is - is it possible to run a pod under a specific service account so the service can connect to the database? (Other approach I took was to impersonate the call with `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated`, however that requires the DLL "advapi32.dll" and I couldn't find a way to deploy it to the Linux container and make it run.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pod can run with the permissions of an Azure Active Directory service account if you install and implement [AAD Pod Identity components](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity) in your cluster.

You'll need to set up an `AzureIdentity` and an `AzureIdentityBinding` resource in your cluster then add a label to the pod(s) that will use permissions associated with the service account.

Please note that this approach relies on the [managed identity or service principal associated with your cluster having the role "Managed Identity Operator"](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/blob/master/docs/readmes/README.role-assignment.md#performing-role-assignments) granted against the service account used to access SQL Server (service account must exist in Azure Active Directory).

I suspect you may have a requirement for the pods to take on the identity of a "group managed service account" which exists in your local AD only. I don't think this is supported in Linux containers ([Recently, Windows nodes support GMSAs as a GA feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-gmsa/)).